# MOQing a controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository, moq-3

I have the following controller

```
 public class ProviderController : Controller
{
    private static readonly IProviderRepository _repository = new ProviderRepository();
    private static readonly Ilogger Logger = new Logger();     

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateProvider(Provider provider)
    {
        try
        {
            int providerCreationSuccessful = _repository.CreateProvider(provider);
            if (providerCreationSuccessful == 1)
                TempData["userIntimation"] = "Provider Registered Successfully";

            return RedirectToAction("ShowTheListOfProviders");
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(Ex.Message);
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
 }
```

The IProviderRepository looks like this.

```
public interface IProviderRepository
{
    List<Provider> GetListofProviders();

    Provider GetSingleProviderDetails(int ProviderID);

    int CreateProvider(Provider provider);

    int DeleteProvider(int ProviderID);

    int UpdateProviderDetails(Provider provider);
}
```

I have to MOQ the controller apparently.I am guessing that means I ahve to MPOQ the methods.So,I created a test project with the following method.

```
 public class ProviderControllerTests
{
    Provider _provider;
    Mock<IProviderRepository> mockProviderRepository;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void InitializeTestData()
    {
        _provider = new Provider();
        mockProviderRepository = new Mock<IProviderRepository>();
    }
  [TestMethod()]
    public void repository_CreateProviderTest()
    {
        //Act
        mockProviderRepository.Setup(provider => provider.CreateProvider(_provider)).Returns(1);
        //Assert
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Could some one guide me on what exactly I need to mock here.I feel like I am a little in over my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock IProviderRepository which you have done.

```
mockProviderRepository = new Mock<IProviderRepository>();
```

In order not to interact with the real database you have to the following

```
[TestInitialize]
    public void InitializeTestData()
    {
        _provider = new Provider();
        mockProviderRepository = new Mock<IProviderRepository>();
        _provider._repository=mockProviderRepository.Object;

    }
```

So you can now test your Actions of the ProviderController using this mocked repository.

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void repository_CreateProviderTest()
    {
        //Act
        mockProviderRepository.Setup(provider => provider.CreateProvider(_provider)).Returns(1);
        Provider provider = new Provider() {//with data};
       _provider.CreateProvider(Provider provider);
       //Your Assertion

}
```

Comment: Wont this access the actual database or does thid mock the database access.

Comment: Sorry, see my edited answer. By assigning _repository in ProviderController to mockProviderRepository it will not touch the actual database.

Comment: But there is no property called _repository in the provider model

Comment: make "private static readonly IProviderRepository _repository" to public